# How can I see which line of the csv file I am on to Logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I have a question. When transferring data to elasticsearch with Logstash, can I see which line of the csv file it is in? For example, the field named path shows me which csv file I am in. So, is there a field or a method that shows which line I am in the csv file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Logstash is reading a file in tail mode it creates `sincedb` file which is used to store checkpoint data while reading is in progress, format is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985012/understanding-sincedb-files-from-logstash-file-input). What you can see is byte offset, I don't think there is a way to see exact line, you would need to find that out yourself from the byte offset.